# How to get the Modelfield - datetime.now

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

i've been strugling a lot with arithmetics on Dates. First of all i got the date between two datetimeFields (models) and thats ok. but i'd like to get the (To_do.end)-datetime.now()

i've got the 2 datefields difference by the :
To_do.objects.annotate(
                     delta=ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - F('start'), output_field=DurationField())

since i've been trying the same with a variable=datetime.now() and still don't get it

thats the test that im trying to get the succes

```
def index(request):
    myDate = datetime.now()
    days_left1 = To_do.objects.annotate(
        delta=ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - myDate, output_field=DurationField()))
    return render(request, 'ongoingtest.html', {
        'myDate': myDate,
        'days_left1': days_left1,
    })
```

thats what i did to get the difference between the two model fields

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'ongoing.html'
    model = To_do

    def get_queryset(self):
        return To_do.objects.annotate(
            delta=ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - F('start'), output_field=DurationField())
        )
```

models.py:

```
class To_do (models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    how = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

just get the  To_do.end - datetime.now()

Comment: Do you really need to do that in the query? A simple model method would do the same job.

Comment: i think'so i've to display the difference for each task(object) created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Now` database function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#now

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

def index(request):
    myDate = datetime.now()
    days_left1 = To_do.objects.annotate(
        delta=ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - Now(), output_field=DurationField()))
    return render(request, 'ongoingtest.html', {
        'myDate': myDate,
        'days_left1': days_left1,
    })
```

Comment: it's displays me <QuerySet [<To_do: Linkar tudo>, <To_do: qwewqewq>]>  (both objects created)

Comment: Yep, so you have two `To_do` objects in your database right now that are being returned from the query. So `days_left1` will be a queryset with those two objects annotated with the `delta` property. You'll need to loop over them and display them in the `ongoingtest.html` template, or you can further filter based on the `delta` annotation if you want before passing them to the template.

Comment: ´´´{% for To_do in days_left1 %}
<li>
  <h2>{{To_do.task}} -  {{To_do.end}} - {{days_left1}} </h2>
</li>
{%endfor%}

Comment: thank you, sir it worked but i'm not getting de difference between create a queryset in a CBV and a FBV. On a FBV should i create a variable and pass by dict?